# Reader not reasiving nessesary code and returns as a null error

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

**My goal:** have the reader read information of the locations and ID (id is the one believed to cause the error) and use my terrain code to create new terrains in the game.

The error was created after I tried implementing the calculation for the terrain ID. I would like to know why this is causing the error and how to fix it.

Calculation Code:

```
static String XCordTex = Window.getTex1();
static String ZCordTex = Window.getTex2();
static int ZCordNum;
static int XCordNum;
static int IDCalculation;

private static final String RES_LOC = "res/";

static int ID = IDCalculation;

public static int parseInteger( String string, int defaultValue ) {
      try {
        return Integer.parseInt(string);
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException e ) {
        return defaultValue;
      }
}

public int IDCalulation(){
    ZCordNum = (int) (parseInteger(Window.getTex1(), 0));
    XCordNum = (int) (parseInteger(Window.getTex2(), 0));
    IDCalculation = XCordNum + ZCordNum;
    return IDCalculation;
}
```

Reader:

```
public static void loadTIDF(){
    try{
        File f = new File(RES_LOC + "terrainFileID.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

        List<Terrain> Terrains = new ArrayList<Terrain>();

         while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
             String line = sc.nextLine();
             String[] details = line.split(":");
             int XCord = Integer.parseInt(details[0]);
             int ZCord = Integer.parseInt(details[1]);
             int ID = Integer.parseInt(details[2]);
             Terrain newTerrain = new Terrain(XCord, ZCord, ID);
             System.out.println("XCord: " + XCord + " ZCord: " + ZCord
                     + " ID: " + ID);
        }

         for(Terrain newTerrain: Terrains){
                System.out.println(newTerrain.toString());
            }


    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
        System.out.println("Broken Reading System");
    }

}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at terrains.TIDF.loadTIDF(TIDF.java:89)
at Run.MainLoop.main(MainLoop.java:171)
```

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KsEq.png)

Comment: what is the input you are giving

Comment: try to print details[0], details[1].. before you parse it and check, is it properly diving strings

Comment: @Raghu yes that is working properly it would outprint the write the correct info, the thing that broke it is when I implemented the codes for calculating the correct ID info

Comment: actually its failing at parseInt. Its getting null string value which cannot be formatted into number. are you sure there will be 3 values in the string input like, A:B:12

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
try{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("terrainFileID.txt"));
    String s;
    while((s = in.readLine()) != null){

        String[] details = s.split(":");

        int XCord = Integer.parseInt(details[0]);
         int ZCord = Integer.parseInt(details[1]);
         int ID = Integer.parseInt(details[2]);
         Terrain newTerrain = new Terrain(XCord, ZCord, ID);
         System.out.println("XCord: " + XCord + " ZCord: " + ZCord
                 + " ID: " + ID);
    }

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this error  NumberFormatException: For input string: "null" should not come if you assign xcord, zcord and id values inside if (!details[i].equals("null")) {//assign here}

Comment: can you please enter sample input here.. how are you giving input

Comment: ill try that while waiting I'm going to post a image update

Comment: imput sample: writer.write(XCordTex + ":" + ZCordTex + ":" + ID);
   writer.newLine();

Comment: I'm going to try tomorrow cant barely stay awake any longer

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue!!!!!! So it came down to the writer not working after the calculation which I didn't catch.

Original: writer.write(XCordTex + ":" + ZCordTex + ":" + ID);

Fix:writer.write((String.valueOf(XCordTex)) + ":" + (String.valueOf(ZCordTex))
                    + ":" + ID);

Note: I found this kinda weird because this was not needed until I changed the ID